# Implementing multinomial-Poisson transformation with multilevel models

Tags: r, lme4

I know variations of this question have been asked before but I haven't yet seen an answer on how to implement the multinomial Poisson transformation with multilevel models.

I decided to make a fake dataset and follow the method outlined [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/105282/logistic-multinomial-regression-as-two-multiple-poisson-regressions), also consulting the notes the poster mentions as well as the Baker paper on MP transformation.

In order to check if I'm doing the coding correctly, I decided to create a binary outcome variable as a first step; because `glmer` can handle binary response variables, this will let me check I'm correctly recasting the logit regression as multiple Poissons.

The context of this problem is running multilevel regressions with survey data where the outcome variable is response to a question and the possible predictors are demographic variables. As I mentioned above, I wanted to see if I could properly code the binary outcome variable as a Poisson regression before moving on to multi-level outcome variables.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lme4)

key <- expand.grid(sex = c('Male', 'Female'),
                   age = c('18-34', '35-64', '45-64'))

set.seed(256)
probs <- runif(nrow(key))

# Make a fake dataset with 1000 responses
n <- 1000
df <- data.frame(sex = sample(c('Male', 'Female'), n, replace = TRUE),
                 age = sample(c('18-34', '35-64', '45-64'), n, replace = TRUE),
                 obs = seq_len(n), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

age <- model.matrix(~ age, data = df)[, -1]
sex <- model.matrix(~ sex, data = df)[, -1]

beta_age <- matrix(c(0, 1), nrow = 2, ncol = 1)
beta_sex <- matrix(1, nrow = 1, ncol = 1)

# Create class probabilities as a function of age and sex
probs <- plogis(
  -0.5 + 
    age %*% beta_age + 
    sex %*% beta_sex +
    rnorm(n)
)

id <- ifelse(probs > 0.5, 1, 0)

df$y1 <- id
df$y2 <- 1 - df$y1

# First run the regular hierarchical logit, just with a varying intercept for age
glm_out <- glmer(y1 ~ (1|age), family = 'binomial', data = df)
summary(glm_out)

#Next, two Poisson regressions
glm_1 <- glmer(y1 ~ (1|obs) + (1|age), data = df, family = 'poisson')
glm_2 <- glmer(y2 ~ (1|obs) + (1|age), data = df, family = 'poisson')
coef(glm_1)$age - coef(glm_2)$age
coef(glm_out)$age
```

The outputs for the last two lines are:

```
> coef(glm_1)$age - coef(glm_2)$age
      (Intercept)
18-34  0.14718933
35-64  0.03718271
45-64  1.67755129
> coef(glm_out)$age
      (Intercept)
18-34  0.13517758
35-64  0.02190587
45-64  1.70852847
```

These estimates seem close but they are not exactly the same. I'm thinking I've specified an equation wrong with the intercept.